# Spacing string in a list view

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio and have made a list and have populated it with the fallowing string. I want to be able to space out the "Electricity" and the "€30" by about 3 tabs it there a simple way of doing this.

```
String[] from = { "Electricity €30","Groceries €20" };
```

Comment: String[] from = { "Electricity \t\t\t€30","Groceries \t\t\t€20" };

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<from.length; i++) {
    from[i].replace(" ", "\t\t\t");
}
```

Comment: Please provide some kind of explanation too inorder to support your answer while asnwering a question..

Answer (score 0):

Add in the string the tab `\t` symbol where you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the String replace function:
replace(" ", "\t\t\t")

Answer (score 0):

**SIMPLE SOLUTION:**

*You have to replace `" €"`with `"\t\t\t€"`. Because if any item name contains one or more space " " (Like this: Book and Stationaries) then it will produce weird output.*

```
for(int i=0; i<from.length; i++) 
{
    from[i].replace(" €", "\t\t\t€");
}
```